# How to authenticate against an MS CRM 2016 IFD instance with javascript?

Tags: javascript, adal, dynamics-crm-2016, adal.js, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to authenticate against our CRM 2016 IFD instance with Javascript to make some Web API calls. How can I do this?
According to the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx), this can be done with ADAL.js, but the answer to [this question on github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/222) says, that the IFD/ADFS scenario is not supported by ADAL.js.

What is the correct approach? Can the authentication be done with ADAL.js or what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327838.aspx) metioned in the post shows the use of ADAL.net which use the Oauth Auth code flow to access the web API. ADAL.js on the other hand is designed to be used with SPAs and uses the Oauth [implicit grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant).

The older ADFS versions don't support the implicit grant flow(which is what the Github issues referred to). The ADFS 2016 has the support for implicit grant. Here is a [documented sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs#modifying-the-sample) of using ADAL.js against ADFS 2016.